# Parse user is logging out even I do not log out

Tags: android, parse-platform

So , this is the Launcher activity when I start the application I check if someone is logged In or not but ParseUser.getCurrentUser() always returns a null I think. When I logIn and then close the application without logging out and start it again, getCurrentUser() again returns a null, but it is not supposed to. The logIn function is in another class called HumLogModel which I written below this one.

```
public class LauncherActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Intent logInActivityIntent;
    private Intent homeActivityIntent;
    private HumLogController humLogController;
    private HumLogModel humLogModel;
    private String username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);
        initializeParse();
        username = getCurrentUser();

        if (username.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            humLogModel = new HumLogModel();
            humLogController = new HumLogController();
            startLogInActivity();
        }
        else {
            humLogModel = new HumLogModel();
            humLogController = new HumLogController();
            startHomeActivity();
        }
    }


 private String getCurrentUser(){
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            return currentUser.getUsername();
        } else {
            return "null";
        }
    }
}
```

This is where we are starting the parse datastore. 
    private void initializeParse(){
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "LrAF8blaE0GR19ffsr78rHKEH50QBcnZFDSuj9BW", "2UBZlOgM78UNj7AcxcArmuOlxy5y3UstpJP1h9lb");
    }

```
 This is the Model class which have the logIn method which are called up when some one log's in and also the logOut method (but even logOut method is never called , user is logged out I think .!!!) 

public class HumLogModel extends Application implements Serializable {

    private  transient ParseObject customer;
    private  transient ParseObject tradesman;
    private  transient ParseObject user;

    public HumLogModel(){
        customer = new ParseObject("Customer");
        tradesman = new ParseObject("Tradesman");
        user = new ParseObject("User");
    }

    public void createNewUser(String username, String password , String userType){
        user.put("username" , username);
        user.put("password", password);
        user.put("userType", userType);
        user.saveInBackground();

        ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
        newUser.setUsername(username);
        newUser.setPassword(password);
        newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                } else {
                    // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
                    // to figure out what went wrong
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void logIn(String username , String password){
        ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                if (user != null) {
                    // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                } else {
                    // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void logOut(){
        ParseUser.logOut();
    }

}
```

When I close the application and start it again it always starts with LogInactivity, but it is not supposed to if do not logOut

Comment: You should initialize Parse in onCreate of your application subclass and not the activity

Comment: Also you should never call 'new HumLogModel' . I think you would benefit from looking at one of the tutorial projects on Parse.com. Perhaps the todo list tutorial

Comment: If I do not call newHumLogMode, how will I access the methods inside it :-(

Comment: What is a subclass, I do not know ...!

Comment: `HumLogModel extends Application` so HumLogModel is a subclass of Application. If setup correctly in your manifest, the onCreate method of HumLogModel will get called when your application is started. See this for an example: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android. It is then in onCreate of HumLogModel you initialize parse. You can read the code of https://parse.com/tutorials/using-the-local-datastore for inspiration.